# Android Java Text not being centered

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make the text all centered but it's not working out. Here's my xml code

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/creditText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:maxLines="6"
android:text="
Dalton Metlzer: Lead Programer/Designer
Cole Selensky: Lead Designer/Programer 
Carson Rego: Lead Artist
Carly R: Logo Artist
Evan Swonke: Music Composer/Performer
Blake Jackson: Narator"
 />
```

instead it just gets all jumbled up.

this is how it looks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDfPy.png

Comment: re-write android:layout_marginTop="0dp"

Comment: I just copied your code & It is looking in center

Comment: Just do one things ctrl+A >> ctrl + shift + F & remove top margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**May be Useful this Code**

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/creditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:text="Dalton 
                   Metlzer: Lead Programer/Designer\n
                   Cole Selensky: Lead Designer/Programer\n 
                   Carson Rego: Lead Artist\n
                   Carly R: Logo Artist\n
                   Evan Swonke: Music Composer/Performer\n
                   Blake Jackson: Narator"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given spaces between those names. I assume you want a vertical list of names centered within the page. In this case, Instead of spaces, at the end of every name, hit enter so you get a newline character. Then you can get a nice centered vertical list of names.

Answer (score 0):

just try this :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/creditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:text="
Dalton Metlzer: Lead Programer/Designer
Cole Selensky: Lead Designer/Programer 
Carson Rego: Lead Artist
Carly R: Logo Artist
Evan Swonke: Music Composer/Performer
Blake Jackson: Narator"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to format your text with new line and all
and than some change inxml file like remove

> android:layout_marginTop="350dp"

new xml code like this

```
 <TextView
android:id="@+id/creditText"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:maxLines="6"
android:text="
Dalton Metlzer: Lead Programer/Designer
Cole Selensky: Lead Designer/Programer 
Carson Rego: Lead Artist
Carly R: Logo Artist
Evan Swonke: Music Composer/Performer
Blake Jackson: Narator"
 />
```

Here I not format text.

Format text as per your requirement.

Comment: the thing is I'm having the text scroll up out of the bottom of the screen that's why im having it at 350

Comment: Ok I understand than you should add that line to your code and format text as per your requirement that's also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

The android:gravity attribute takes effect in the content of the TextView but as you have also android:layout_width="wrap_content" you don't have where to center on.

Either put

```
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

to grow the TextView and center internally, or

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontally"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to keep the minimal width of the TextView and center it on it's parent